# center element with flex box under flex grow constraints

Tags: css, flexbox

I've created a table with 9 elements, divs inside divs (cells in rows).

In order to achieve the same width I user the following properties for the child div:

```
flex: 1
```

parent div:

```
display: flex
```

So it worked ok, and all the cells are at the same side.
But I can I center the content inside them?
using `align-items` and `justify-content` doesn't work

Comment: You have to also add `display: flex` to the child div.